# Java not focusing any component

Tags: java, swing, awt, components

I use a `c1.setFocusable(false)` so that my Checkbox c1 is not focused as shown in the pic and after that, focus goes to the next Checkbox c2, I use again `c2.setFocusable(false)` and it continues to all Checkboxes. Even if it doesn't find one, it continues to the next JTextField. Is there a way to not let the focus go to something instead of setting focusable to all my numerous components?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Is setting a custom focus traversal policy (as explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal)) what you are looking for ?

Comment: I have some components. The first one is in some grey border aka focusable, but I don't want it or any of them to be focusable. So, if I use setFocusable(false), focus goes to the next one and so on. ..

Comment: But what is the purpose of having an editable component which cannot receive focus ? What is the user supposed to do with it ? If you want to disable a certain component, use `setEnabled( false )`

Comment: added a pic, how can I get rid of that grey border thing? :O

Comment: @Robin I think that is about dootted borders only

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get rid of that grey border thing?

Why would you want to do that? That "grey border thing" is the focus indicator. It is used to provide information to the user so the user knows which component has focus.

If you really want to confuse the user and make them guess which component has focus then you can use:

```
button.setFocusPainted( false );
```

Comment: "The method setFocusPainted(boolean) is undefined for the type Checkbox" and if I change it to setFocusable I go back to my initial question

Comment: @GiannisThanasiou, sure it is. Read the API. It is inherited from AbstractButton. `if I change it to setFocusable I go back to my initial question` - like the other people who have commented, I don't understand that question and did not attempt to answer it. I directly answered the "grey border thing".